# Problemas con una consulta en laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Quiero traer el nombre,num_empleado,vigencia,ano_contratacion,gerencia,unidad_ejecutora,actividad_obra de empleados por ejemplo tengo un select y ala hora de seleccionar el nombre estos datos tienen que mostrarseme el problema que en empleado solo guardo los id de ano_contratacion,gerencia,unidad_ejecutora,actividad_obra y yo quiero los nombres y no los id estos datos los traigo de organizador_tareas el cual los jala de sus tablas correspondientes

[image]

esta es la funcion en la cual estaba haciendo la prueba

```
public static function empleado_accion($id){

        return   \DB::table('empleado')
            ->join('unidades','unidades.id','=','empleado.unidad_ejecutora')
            ->select('empleado.id','unidades.id as id_sco','empleado.num_empleado','vigencia','ano_contratacion','gerencia','unidad_ejecutora','actividad_obra')->where('id','=',$id)->get();

    }
```

este es el error que me tira ala hora de realizarlo

message SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `empleado`.`id`, `unidades`.`id` as `id_sco`, `unidades`.`unidad`, `empleado`.`num_empleado`, `vigencia`, `ano_contratacion`, `gerencia`, `unidad_ejecutora`, `actividad_obra` from `empleado` inner join `unidades` on `unidades`.`id` = `empleado`.`unidad_ejecutora` where `id` = 5)

Comment: Intenta cambiar el `get` del final por `first()`

Comment: tengo el mismo problema no puedo obtener el nombre

Comment: los id que guardo en empleado de ano_contratacion,gerencia,unidad_ejecutora,actividad_obra son los id de organizador tareas el cual tiene los id de anos_trabajo,gerencia,unidades, y asi

Comment: No ocupas en absoluto eloquent?

Comment: En el where intenta acceder al id asi `empleado.id, '=', $id`

Comment: muchas gracias solo eso tenia que agregarle

Comment: Por nada, agrego la respuesta en donde va para otros usuarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto

```
public static function empleado_accion($id){

        return   \DB::table('empleado')
            ->join('unidades','unidades.id','=','empleado.unidad_ejecutora')
            ->select('empleado.id','unidades.id as id_sco','empleado.num_empleado','vigencia','ano_contratacion','gerencia','unidad_ejecutora','actividad_obra')->where('id','=',$id)->get();

    }
```

por esto: Agregar

> empleado.id en el where

```
public static function empleado_accion($id){

        return   \DB::table('empleado')
            ->join('unidades','unidades.id','=','empleado.unidad_ejecutora')
            ->select('empleado.id','unidades.id as id_sco','empleado.num_empleado','vigencia','ano_contratacion','gerencia','unidad_ejecutora','actividad_obra')->where('empleado.id','=',$id)->get();

    }
```